# How to compare two objects in an array and replace it's values if they are equal

Tags: java, arrays

For instance, I am creating and storing objects with three parameters `(Bob, Marley, 55)` with a `Scanner` in an array of objects and while input does not equal to `stop` it keeps storing. I need to find out while looping if the first name equals to any object's first name in an array if so I want to replace its age.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please share your tried attempt as well.

Comment: You want to replace any "Bob" person’s age with the age of some other person named “Bob”? Does not make sense. Please search Stack Overflow. The solution to this kind of problem is almost certainly covered already.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, You can use a map where your key will be first name and the the object will be value. Pseudo code will be like.Let me know if I missed anything.

```
yourObject obj;
Map<String, yourObject> mapBasedOnFirstName = new Hashmap<>();

if (mapBasedOnFirstName.contains(obj.getFirstName)) {
yourObject obj2 = mapBasedOnFirstName.get(obj.getFirstName);
obj2.setAge(obj.getAge);
}
```